# Drop packet intentionally using Wireshark

Tags: macos, wireshark

Can I drop packets using Wireshark? I want a particular HTTP request sent from an application running on my Mac to be dropped.
In Burp Suite we can drop a packet by setting proxy in browser, can I achieve the same for packet going from an app running in MacOS? Or are there any other tools to achieve the same.

Comment: More suitable for Superuser

Comment: can you elaborate please

Comment: I think, it is not about programming ; it is more suitable for Superuser, forum from Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is a tool called 'Network Link Conditioner'. I was made aware of the tool reading 'iOS 9 SDK Development' by pragprog.com (page 163).

This is the instruction from the book (PDF):

Fortunately, a Mac can simulate lousy network conditions for this kind of testing. From the Xcode menu, select Open Developer Tool > More Developer Tools to be taken to Apple’s Xcode downloads page. After asking for a developer ID and password, the page shows optional downloads for Xcode. Look for the latest version of the Hardware IO Tools For Xcode, download it, and double-click the Network Link Condition- er.prefPane to install it.

This will add this tool to your system settings. Here you can simulate packet drops, set up- and download speed etc.

Comment: This is a third party application. Is that okey

Comment: This tool is now in "Additional Tools for Xcode"